# Apache Camel: Access original data (XML) returned from WebService

Tags: java, xml, apache-camel, transformation, webservice-client

I am using Apache Camel to access a WebService.
I am trying to inject content into the data I receive from the WebService for testing purposes.
Using getBody(), I only can access the Java objects which were deserialized from the received XML. Does anybody know how I can access the original XML - before deserialization by Camel?

This is my route structure. As you can see, I create a proxy Webservice from bean eaigateway to the real WebService (bean webservice) I am querying.

```
from("cxf:bean:eaigateway")
        .routeId(ROUTE_ID_GATEWAY)
             .process(new EnrichBean())
            .to(ENDPOINT_WEBSERVICE)
            .process(new DisenrichBean())
    ;



from(ENDPOINT_WEBSERVICE)
        .routeId(ROUTE_ID_WEBSERVICE)
        .to("cxf:bean:webservice")
    ;


public class DisenrichBean implements Processor {

@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

        // This contains the unserialized object returned from the webservice.
        // But how to get and set the original XML content?  
        Object  antwort = ((MessageContentsList)(exchange.getIn().getBody())).get(0);

    }
}
```

Comment: Set the `dataFormat` property to `PAYLOAD` in your CXF configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Original message should be available from:

```
exchange.getUnitOfWork().getOriginalInMessage()
```

But in your case it seems like you need Object/XML marshalling.
Some example can be found here: http://camel.apache.org/data-format.html